# jquery: Finding the last child from a selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, I've got a selector here

```
var $myNeeds = $('.history');
```

This selector would have multiple divs inside, and now I want to get the last child from it, how to do this?

I tried `$myNeeds.last()`, this won't work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively....

```
$myNeeds.find('>:last-child')
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/aFMsn/).

Comment: @SLaks Seems to work in the fiddle, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @SLaks To be honest, I didn't think it would work until I tested it :)

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there...

```
$myNeeds.children().last()
```

The `last` method gets the last element *in your set*.
You want the last *child* of your set, so you need to get a new set with the children.

You could also write

```
$('.history > :last-child')
```

or

```
$myNeeds.children(":last")
```